# How can I find mid-level influencers on Instagram?

Tags: instagram, followers

I'd like to hire social influencers for an app I'm launching. The app is for 20-somethings who go to clubs and bars. I have a low budget, so I'd like to find some mid-level Instagram influencers (100k-500k followers) whose followers fit in my target market. After I find them, I'll contact and hopefully hire them.

Any suggestions?

SocialBlade shows lists of top Instagrammers, but I haven't been able to find *mid-level* Instagrammers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about _using_ a web application.

Comment: @ale Oh, good point! Sorry, this was my first question on this stackexchange community. I'll make my future questions focus on _using_ web applications. (It sure would be nice if Instagram had a feature that allowed members to search for other members based on follower count, but apparently it doesn't.)

Answer (score 2):

Instagram is notoriously bad at being able to provide a high-quality wide range of analytical tools to their users - that is just a known fact.

My take-away from this question was that you just (basically) do not wish to employ the top-level 'Influencers' to your Instgram presence, but instead would like to things in a mid-level range.

Now, if this is correct, there are very few options for having such a specific set of standards on a site with such little growth in that market - **but** you are definitely not completely without options. I will try to keep it short but detailed, but from what I understand:

- There are a couple main websites through which a large portion of Instagram users obtain influencers. Of course there are far fewer users who are aiming at that slightly lower area (for whatever reason) and it has caused a delay in such tools. However, Instagram is actually on more of a leading-edge than they have been in the past several years, and I believe it is becoming easier and easier to make a more targeted choice of what you want and **how** you want it.

I actually gave this quite a bit of thought and subsequent research, and I actually only found one site\company who seems to be very open about the way by which they allow customers\clients to decide upon the type of services rendered.

The website - which I will list below in a link - has three main paayment plans (for Promoters) and a couple more for Business owners. If you havent decided on specifics yet, I highly recommend visiting them and signing up for a quick "Free" minimum-access account just to audit the quality of service.

Furthermore, if you actually browse through Google \ Bing \ Etc, with the approriate keywords, you might be surprised at what you find and may even come to an entirely different conclusion. I will post a list of relevant keywords below with the think to the site, so that if by chance you are unable to produce appropriate search terms you will have at least something to work with.

Im hoping that I understood your question correctly, but if for some reason I have left anything out or I have completely missed the ball, please feel free to provide some feedback and I would be more than happy to ascertain some additional information for you.

**Link and Keywords Below:**

Site: http://www.instapromotr.com.au/

Keywords: wildcard, advanced, search, sort, influencers, Instagram, analytics, business, mid, mid-level, sort, median, promotion, promoter.

^ For the keywords, Im going to just assume that if you happen to need to use any, you will be able to piece it all together.

Comment: Thank you very much for all this research, and for your long, thoughtful, detailed answer! Unfortunately your site focuses on Australian influencers, and I need to focus on the United States to build on my field marketing efforts. I have been browsing via Google and found some other "middleman" companies that promise to connect businesses with influencers. I was hoping to contact influencers directly, but I may just need to pay some company(ies) for the service.

Comment: From what I gathered, it seems like the simplest way would be the latter - but I'm sure it's more than  feasible either way, due to the amazing state of the company. . As for the fact that the site was located in AU - I was aware of it but the site led me to believe that since they're a predominantly "online" service provider, they might have still been a feasible option. I apologize for not mentioning that; I've only been a member here for one day so I've been attempting to answer and get as much feedback as possible to improve, so I greatly appreciate you taking the time to  let me know.

Comment: Thanks @AustinTylerFrye! I've been a member of this community for a few hours less than you, and I got feedback that my questions didn't even adhere to the community guidelines. Whoops! But now I know! We're both learning.